# Converting .xml to .csv Feed

Tags: xml, csv

So I'm trying to convert an .xml data feed:

[image]

into a .csv but formatted in this format

[image: http://www.shoptab.net/blog/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/step4_datafeed.jpg]

I have repeating elements such as "title" "description" etc and I want to take them from the entirely vertical xml format and break out each element into a separate column.

I've found a [tool](https://code.google.com/p/xml2csv-conv/) that I believe does exactly this but I can't understand how to set it up

I've got two files - a .bat and .jar. Within the .bat we have the following default code:

`java -jar xml2csv-conv.jar %*`

I'm not sure how I go about modifying this. Could anyone provide some advice?

Comment: What is the result of running the batch file over your input file?

Comment: That's precisely the problem. I feel like a fool as I can't get it to run over my file (named feed1.xml).

Comment: The documentation at your link says to use `xml2csv-conv feed1.xml feed1.csv` -- does this not work?

Comment: But that doesn't initiate the .jar file that comes with the tool.

Comment: Then use the alternative command form: `java -jar xml2csv-conv.jar [-options] <source filename or url> <destination filename>`, or in your case, `java -jar xml2csv-conv.jar feed1.xml feed1.csv`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if the channel-section is repeating, the item-section though apparently is. To turn this into a sane CSV-structure you need to know the number of repeated `<item>`s. Because you need to know how many columns you have to provide.

Anyway - the data is in your case structured in such a way that the name of a key is the name of the tag and its content is the value.

My suggestion would be to try applying XPath to your situation like this:

```
<root>
  <record id="1">
    <keyA>val_1A</keyA>
    <keyB>val_1B</keyB>
  </record>
  <record id="2">
    <keyA>val_2A</keyA>
    <keyB>val_2B</keyB>
  </record>
  <record id="3">
    <keyA>val_3A</keyA>
    <keyB>val_3B</keyB>
  </record>
</root>
```

With xmlstarlet you could parse this XML document (test.xml):

```
xmlstarlet \
    sel -T -t -m /root/record \
      -v "concat(@id,';',keyA,';',keyB)" \
      -n test.xml

1;val_1A;val_1B
2;val_2A;val_2B
3;val_3A;val_3B
```

You can find further examples and more explanations in the following tutorial:

[Transforming an XML Document into a CSV using XMLStarlet](http://www.joyofdata.de/blog/transforming-xml-document-into-csv-using-xmlstarlet/)

Answer (score 0):

You can write pretty simple Python script, that reads XML using [lxml](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/lxml/3.6.3) and writes CSV using the csv module from Python standard library.

`xml_to_csv.py`:

```python
import argparse
import csv
from lxml import etree
import sys

def main():
    p = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    p.add_argument('xml_file')
    args = p.parse_args()
    xml_str = open(args.xml_file, 'rb').read()
    root = etree.XML(xml_str)
    w = csv.DictWriter(
        sys.stdout,
        fieldnames='''
            title description link
        '''.split())
    w.writeheader()
    for item in root.findall('./channel/item'):
        row = {
            'title': item.find('./title').text,
            'description': item.find('./description').text,
            'link': item.find('./link').text,
        }
        w.writerow(row)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

`feed.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" ?>
<rss version="0.91">
    <channel>
        <title>Delphi Programming</title>
        <item>
            <title>How to draw rotated text</title>
            <link>http://delphi.about.com/1234.html</link>
            <description>This example creates...</description>
        </item>
        <item>
            <title>FutureValue function</title>
            <link>http://delphi.about.com/5678.html</link>
            <description>Returns the future...</description>
        </item>
    </channel>
</rss>
```

Usage:

```
$ pip install lxml # if needed
$ python3 xml_to_csv.py  feed.xml 
title,description,link
How to draw rotated text,This example creates...,http://delphi.about.com/1234.html
FutureValue function,Returns the future...,http://delphi.about.com/5678.html
```